# How to cancel http request in broadcast receiver?

Tags: android, web-services, http, broadcastreceiver

In my app, I am using broadcast receiver to capture the internet connect and disconnect state. Its working fine. Here is the code:

```
public class CheckConnectivity extends BroadcastReceiver{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent arg1) {

        boolean isNotConnected = arg1.getBooleanExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NO_CONNECTIVITY, false);
        if(isNotConnected){
            Toast.makeText(context, "Disconnected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Connected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }
}
```

I am using http web services in my app. I wrote them in different class.
HttpConnect.java:

```
public class HttpConnect {
    public static String finalResponse;
    public static HttpURLConnection con = null;
    public static String  sendGet(String url)  {

        try {
            StringBuffer response = null;
            //String urlEncode = URLEncoder.encode(url, "UTF-8");
            URL obj = new URL(url);
            Log.e("url", obj.toString());

            con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

            // optional default is GET
            con.setRequestMethod("GET");

            //add request header
            con.setConnectTimeout(10000);
            int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();

            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
            String inputLine;
            response = new StringBuffer();

            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(inputLine);
            }
            in.close();
            finalResponse  = response.toString();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //print result
        return finalResponse;

    }
}
```

My problem is, how to disconnect or cancel http request when broadcast receiver says no connectivity.
I have tried this code below:

```
if(isNotConnected){
            Toast.makeText(context, "Disconnected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            if(HttpConnect.con != null)
            {
                HttpConnect.con.disconnect();
            }
        }
```

But its not working. Can anybody tell me how to cancel http request when broadcast receiver captures lost connection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create one method like as below:

```
 public static boolean isOnline(Context mContext) {
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

And before your http call, you should just check, if it returns `true`, it means internet is available and if it is `false`, it means internet not available and you can stop your http call.

Also, if your call is already initiated, you should set request timeout value there like 30 seconds, if there is no internet, you will get exception of `TimeoutError`

Comment: Nope, you should handle exception and show appropriate message to user or retry or what ever way you like to handle as per application flow.